# AzerothCore with Gdb, restarter and crashlog?

Tags: azerothcore

How can I enable **crashlogs**, **gdb** and **restarter** an AzerothCore server? I can not find any information about this, please help.

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE 28/04/2021

The official guide is available here: https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/how-to-restart-and-debug

#### Using acore dashboard

Here you can find the restarters for linux/bash environments: https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/tree/master/apps/startup-scripts

Those scripts are automatically copied after the compilation to the `/dist` directory if you're using our `./acore.sh` dashboard

You can copy the `conf.sh.dist` and create a `conf-world.sh` file to customize those documented configurations (do the same for the `conf-auth.sh`). In this way, you have both restarter and gdb pre-configured to create a `gdb.txt` (crashdump) file when the core crashes. Make sure to use `RelWithDebInfo` or `Debug` compilation (in your CMake command) in order to get meaningful crash reports.

Then copy the `restarter-world.sh` and the `restarter-auth.sh` from the "examples" beside your conf file and in the same folder of the "run-engine" file.

Eventually you will have something like this:

[image: example]

Run those 2 restarter script to have both authserver and worldserver restarters with gdb support.

**RESTARTERS (without gdb support)**

You can also use `./acore.sh run-worldserver` and `./acore.sh run-authserver`

They both work out of the box when you compile with the dashboard

#### Manual way

Always make sure to use **RelWithDebInfo** or **Debug** compilation (in your CMake command) in order to get meaningful crash reports.

Create a file called `gdb.conf` with this inside:

```
set logging on
set debug timestamp
run -c ../etc/worldserver.conf
bt
```

Then, to debug or create a crashdump you can just use the gdb command as described in its documentation:

```
gdb -x gdb.conf --batch ./worldserver
```

This command should be enough to both attach your IDE to debug your code and also generate a crashdump when the server crashes

For an "universal" and more advanced restarter, Personally I'm using [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

```
pm2 start "gdb -x gdb.conf --batch ./worldserver"
```

It should be enough to automatically restart, monitoring and gdb your server

#### USING DOCKER

Work in progress...